# 404 error occured when post the form in my plugin

Tags: wordpress, forms, http-status-code-404

i have a plugin in my wordpress setup. When i send my form data to same page with plugin, 404 page is coming.

I have no input named as "name".
my form page is above. my plugin is one page plugin and it has tabs. tabs mean is it coded with "if" controller.

```
    //Ana Kategori Sayfası
$oku = file_get_contents('http://www.ddizi.org');
$dizibasla2 = explode ('<div class="blok-liste">', $oku);
$dizibasla = explode ('</ul>',$dizibasla2[1]);
$kaynak = $dizibasla[0];
$diziana = preg_match_all('/<li><a href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a><\/li>/i', $kaynak, $sonuc);
echo '<center>';
echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<select name="anasayfa">';
for($a=0; $a<$diziana; $a++){
echo '<option value="'.$sonuc[1][$a].'">'.$sonuc[2][$a].'</option>';
}
echo '<option value="">-------Eskiler-------</option>';
$dizibasla22 = explode ('<div class="blok-liste">', $oku);
$dizibaslaa = explode ('</ul>',$dizibasla22[2]);
$kaynakss = $dizibaslaa[0];
$dizianaa = preg_match_all('/<li><a href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a><\/li>/i', $kaynakss, $sonuc2);
for($a=0; $a<$dizianaa; $a++){
echo '<option value="'.$sonuc2[1][$a].'">'.$sonuc2[2][$a].'</option>';
}
echo '<option value="">-------Yarışma-------</option>';
$dizibaslaa22 = explode ('<div class="blok-liste">', $oku);
$dizibaslaaa = explode ('</ul>',$dizibaslaa22[4]);
$kaynaksss = $dizibaslaaa[0];
$dizianaaa = preg_match_all('/<li><a href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a><\/li>/i', $kaynaksss, $sonuca2);
for($a=0; $a<$dizianaaa; $a++){
echo '<option value="'.$sonuca2[1][$a].'">'.$sonuca2[2][$a].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo 'Sayfa :<select name="sayfa">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>';
echo $kategoriler;
echo '<input type="submit" name="bolumler" value="Tüm Bölümler">';
echo '</form>';
echo '</center>';
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: make sure you have an absolute or relative path in your form url

Comment: i added my form to my question.